# "error: conflicting types for ‘sem_t’" when compiling eglibc-2.19 on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors, building, eglibc

I was trying to build eglibc-2.19 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS which I downloaded through

```
apt-get source libc6
```

I followed the INSTALL instructions but got this error when it ran into nptl

```
gcc sem_init.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -fno-stack-protector -O2 -Wall -Winline -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes      -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl  -I/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix  -I../ports/sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../libpthread/sysdeps/posix  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../nptl/sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I../libpthread/include -I../libpthread  -I../nptl  -I../ports  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -I../libpthread/include  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h   -DNOT_IN_libc=1 -DIS_IN_libpthread=1 -DIN_LIB=libpthread    -o /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o -MD -MP -MF /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o.dt -MT /home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:28:0: warning: "SEM_FAILED" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define SEM_FAILED ((void *) 0)
 ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:33:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SEM_FAILED      ((sem_t *) 0)
 ^
In file included from sem_init.c:20:0:
../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:30:28: error: conflicting types for ‘sem_t’
 typedef struct __semaphore sem_t;
                            ^
In file included from ../libpthread/include/semaphore.h:26:0,
                 from sem_init.c:20:
../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/semaphore.h:40:3: note: previous declaration of ‘sem_t’ was here
 } sem_t;
   ^
make[2]: *** [/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/glibc-build/nptl/sem_init.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/eglibc-2.19/nptl'
make[1]: *** [nptl/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gpanda/wksp/glibc/tmp2/eglibc-2.19'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this some kind of conflict between libpthread and nptl? How to fix this  problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider LinuxThreads has been superseded by NPTL, so I just removed the add-on libpthread from the eglibc directory, and re-did the configure and make, then everything seems to be ok now.

see [LinuxThreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxThreads,),[NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library)

BTW, since I didn't use the standard /usr path as the "--prefix=" option for configure, so I need copy libstdc++.so.6 and libgcc_s.so.1 to my current build path to get "make check" pass.

see [glibc Known_testsuite_failures](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Testsuite#Known_testsuite_failures)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because I ran a plain `./configure --prefix=/opt`, so I ran `apt-get source -b eglibc` instead and I noted the configure flags it used:

```
(exec 3>&1; exit `( ( (  cd build-tree/i386-libc && CC="i686-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8" CXX="i686-linux-gnu-g++-4.8" AUTOCONF=false MAKEINFO=: /home/sashoalm/Workspace/apt-get-source/libc/eglibc-2.19/configure --host=i686-linux-gnu --build=$configure_build --prefix=/usr --without-cvs --enable-add-ons=libidn,"nptl " --enable-profile --without-selinux --enable-stackguard-randomization --enable-obsolete-rpc --with-pkgversion="Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9" --with-bugurl="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bugs"   --with-headers=/home/sashoalm/Workspace/apt-get-source/libc/eglibc-2.19/debian/include --enable-kernel=2.6.24 --with-selinux --enable-multi-arch ) 2>&1 3>&-; echo $? >&4) | tee  -a build-tree/log-build-i686-linux-gnu-libc >&3) 4>&1`)
```

The command is rather involved, more complex than usual for `apt-get source`, since glibc insists on being built from a separate directory. The actual configure flags are:

`--host=i686-linux-gnu --build=$configure_build --prefix=/usr --without-cvs --enable-add-ons=libidn,"nptl " --enable-profile --without-selinux --enable-stackguard-randomization --enable-obsolete-rpc --with-pkgversion="Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9" --with-bugurl="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bugs"   --with-headers=/home/sashoalm/Workspace/apt-get-source/libc/eglibc-2.19/debian/include --enable-kernel=2.6.24 --with-selinux --enable-multi-arch`

It works with those arguments of course, since that's what Ubuntu maintainers used to compile the package with.

I don't really know which of those flags prevents the error, but if you use that command, or the exact arguments provided by `apt-get source -b eglibc` on your Ubuntu system, it should work well enough.